# docker-compose container cannot access Internet

Tags: docker, centos

I'm not using any proxy. But my hosting provider has it's own nameservers which configured fine and work. I have set them also in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Restarted docker & tested. Then checked journal and saw that those nameservers responded fine. I also know that docker-compose create custom user network for containers in build and that those are not using resolv.conf's nameservers and instead used built in DNS server within docker. Still i need ability to install something inside containers and even `apt-get update` are failed, how can i fix this?

```
apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to downloads.mariadb.com:80 (172.67.32.229), connection timed out Could not connect to downloads.mariadb.com:80 (104.20.68.208), connection timed out Could not connect to downloads.mariadb.com:80 (104.20.67.208), connection timed out
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.4/repo/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to downloads.mariadb.com:80 (172.67.32.229), connection timed out Could not connect to downloads.mariadb.com:80 (104.20.68.208), connection timed out Could not connect to downloads.mariadb.com:80 (104.20.67.208), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

iptables rules outside the container(on host machine):

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

It's just connection timed out. I don't think it is nameservers. And firewalld (NetworkManager) are not installed at all, since it have conflict with docker. Thanks, if anyone will be able to help me.

Comment: you are behind a proxy?

Comment: My hosting provider is godaddy, it's their virtual server. As far as I know, I'm not behind proxy. But there is custom dns servers IPs used, provided by godaddy. As you can see in the logs here IP addresses are present which means they are resolved fine. But no connection. Must be iptables rules maybe.